# Writing a custom Neo4j record inserter

Tags: neo4j

I have a requirement to be able to insert batches of nodes frequently. It could be new insertions totally or updates to existing nodes (and the relationships).

After playing with BatchInsert facilities in Neo4j, I figured out a limitation that when my next batch of nodes arrive, I cannot just update them into the graph (or add them to the graph). Instead, I will have to load everything else I had previously loaded again from the beginning.

I delved into the neo4j-kernel codebase to see if I can implement a Custom Importer which will allow me to import and update as new data arrives. BatchInserterImpl seems to be the class where the meat of the logic is happening to createNodes, createRelationships, etc. As expected, I see that, the nodestore (NeoStore object) is created fresh in the constructor.

How do I get around this problem? Are there other implementations of inserting data where, updates are taken care of, so that, I don't have to re-import everything I have already added to the graph db? If not, what are your recommendations on extending existing code to help my usecase?

I also will need to add indexing and support transactions (at least at a basic level).

Comment: How much data do you need to import? Why not just insert it in a transaction?

Comment: I will be importing huge data (~million) and plan on writing a custom ingester library that talks to Neo4j DB. Ideally, I would like to use an inserter that helps me do initial batch import and real times updates to nodes and relationships later on.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you should use EmbeddedGraphDatabase. BatchInserter is mainly for doing initial large-scale insertion. Once that has been done you should switch over to an EmbeddedGraphDatabase which supports concurrent reads/writes and transactions and what not.

Comment: Is there an example that shows how to update nodes using EmbeddedGraphDatabase? Also, I am I always required to use BatchInserter for the first pass & then switch to EmbeddedGraphDatabase. Why not use EmbeddedGraphDatabase for the initial batch import as well? Does it has any limitations? Thanks!

Comment: Also, assuming I use EmbeddedGraphDatabase as below:
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase( "var/graphDb" );

I can see that GraphDatabaseService Interface has createNode(), but how do I do updates to an existing node or relationship?
I do not see any update method.